# Circuit Analysis Circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

I have a question about the problem below. I have attached my work, but the answer I am getting a different answer than the given answer. Please explain.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please upload your image to the site so that we don't have to follow links to understand your question and so that the question still make sense when the link dies.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the information from the off-site link into it.

Comment: There are 3 power sources , show all detailed assumptions for It, try again with searching how to do.

Comment: Golden, you are a long way away from getting the answer. Where did you get \$I_t=1\:\text{A}\$ and why do you think you can just apply it like that to only two resistors in that circuit?? Your work (and thank you for showing it) illustrates that you have a lot yet to learn and master before you can work this problem. Perhaps you could re-phrase your question? (It would take a chapter or two of writing to teach you what you appear to need to know. Do you even know how to work out two nodal equations and then solve them simultaneously?)

Answer (score 2):

As requested in your question, the explanation to why you get different answer is that you don't calculate as per the circuit given, but a circuit with only one supply and two resistors. Thus the result does not match with the circuit given, which has many more supplies and resistors.

Comment: Maybe the OP replaced the voltage source to a current one and (wrongly) applied current  division only to resistors with 5 and 6 Ohms. And stopped there.

Comment: +1 for giving an answer that encourages the OP along the path of understanding and learning.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake here is you are simply ignoring the components to the right of the 5-ohm resistor.  These components have an effect on the current through that resistor and have to be taken into account.  You will need to do a nodal analysis on the entire circuit